ConcurrentAppendException for tables with 2 different checkpoints in Databricks pipeline
My Databricks table is updated through two distinct streaming processes/pipelines, each having its own checkpoints. When new inputs are simultaneously added to both pipelines, I encounter the following error.
delta.exceptions.ConcurrentAppendException: Files were added to the root of the table by a concurrent update. Please try the operation again.
Is there a method to manage this scenario?
def write_table(outputDF: DataFrame, catalog: str):
outputTable = "table_name1"
checkpoint = (
f"/chkpoints/"
)
(
    outputDF.writeStream.format("delta")
    .foreachBatch(lambda df, batchId: funcDelta(df, batchId, outputTable, catalog))
    .outputMode("update")
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint)
    .start()
)

def funcDelta(batchDF, batchId, writeTable, catalog):
global delta_lock  # Declare the lock as global
# Acquire the lock before accessing Delta table
delta_lock.acquire()

try:

    if not batchDF._jdf.sparkSession().catalog().tableExists(writeTable):
        batchDF.filter("false").write.mode("append").saveAsTable(writeTable)

    # Set the dataframe to view name
    batchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("updates")

    batchDF._jdf.sparkSession().sql(writeTable)
finally:
    # Release the lock after accessing Delta table
    delta_lock.release()

This is the code I'm using
